# sql server 2014 "localhost\instancename" is not connecting via sql authentication but when connected as "localhost" its working

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have 2 sql servers in my local system with the instance name below

```
sql 2017 - MSSQLserver01
sql 2014 - MSSQLServer
```

the 2 services are running perfectly. when i tried to connect to sql 2014 with SSMS 2017 with "localhost" as servername i can able to login to server with sa username. But when i tried to connect as "localhost\MSSQLServer" i am getting connection string error 87. also if i tried to connect 2017 server as "localhost\MSSQLServer01" i can able to connect.

let me know is there any setting/configuration i am missing for sql 2014 installation.

Comment: My recollection is that "MSSQLServer" is the default service and therefore it does not have an InstanceName.

Answer (score 1):

i can able to resolve the issue by creating one more instance for sqlexpress . when connecting that instance as "localhost\sqlexpress8" i can able to connect it in ssms 2017.